# remainders of three consecutive primes when product of each two is divided by the third

Tags: prime-numbers

Take three consecutive primes p,q,r and find the three remainders for $$p\cdot q\mod r$$ $$p\cdot r\mod q$$ $$q\cdot r\mod p$$  Is it possible for all three remainders to be prime?

Comment: How many examples have you looked at?

Comment: Please edit to indicate your efforts.  Brute force searching works here.

Comment: Someone did toss this into a computer and found NO examples.  If this is true that never will all three remainders be primes, is there a proof of this?  I found example with two remainders being primes and the other an even number and a few with all three remainders being odd.

Comment: @lulu : So you can cite an example with $p,q,r$ less than $10^{10}$?

Comment: For p=29, remainders are 11,19,16.  For p=11, remainders are 1,5,7. For p=47, remainders are 13,17,25.

Comment: @EricTowers  I see $\{37,41,47\}$ as an example.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @EricTowers  Ah, I missed the condition that they be consecutive primes.  I agree, that's  harder.

Comment: If there are two primes between $p$ and $p+\sqrt p$ then $qr\pmod p=(q-p)(r-p)$

Comment: If Empy2 speaks truth, then clearly it is not possible to have all three remainders being primes.

Comment: I concede because I didn't study what I already knew about the short cut for to find remainders.  I did notice that for smaller primes 47*59mod53=17 and 47*53mod59=13 giving two consecutive primes (unknown so far?) and that 43*53mod47=23 and 43*47mod53=7.  Could this be the end to the question of finding two prime remainders?

Comment: J.M. as far as anyone can calculate, there are primes between $p$ and $p+ \sqrt p$ for $p$ over some modest threshold, and at least two primes for a slightly less modest threshold. Suggest you run this on computer yourself. There is actually no proof, the best exponent with proof is something like $p + p^{0.58}$ for sufficiently large $p.$  Big gap between computations and what can be proved

Comment: Even if all three remainders cannot be primes, the problem of finding two remainders from p*qmodr and p*rmodq is still unanswered.  If an indefinite number contain two prime remainders can be found, then the question is worthwhile.  I am assuming that others DO have computers and enjoy putting their electrons to work  to answer unusual questions.

Comment: @J.M.Bergot My program is still running, but I should have displayed the progress. But it seems that beyond $p=47$, even the first two expressions are rarely (or never) both prime.

Comment: I decided to restart (this time the progress is displayed)

Comment: I passed $10^{10}$ and found no further triple making the first two expressions simultaneously prime.

Comment: I stopped at $38\cdot 10^9$

Comment: For expression did you use  for three consecutive primes p,q,r p*r mod q   and p*q mod r?  One is seeking two out of the three and q*r mod p is NOT included.